# Question about the phase difference along a keyhole contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am trying to perform an integration along a keyhole contour where the integrand involves $\log z$ and $\log(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})$.
Choosing the principal branch for the functions $\log z$ and $\sqrt{1+z^2}$, we have the following configuration in the complex plane:

[image]

Then by setting $z = i y$ (with $y>1$ on both contours), we have

**On the contour $C_1$:**
$$ \log z = \log y + i \, 5 \pi / 2 \, ,$$
and
$$ \begin{align}
\log(1+\sqrt{1+z^2}) &= \log \left( 1+ \sqrt{y^2-1} \, e^{i \pi / 2} \right) \\
&= \log y + i \, \arctan\left( \sqrt{y^2-1} \right) \, .
\end{align} $$

**On the contour $C_2$:**
$$ \log z = \log y + i \, \pi / 2 \, ,$$
and
$$ \begin{align}
\log(1+\sqrt{1+z^2}) &= \log \left( 1+ \sqrt{y^2-1} \, e^{-i \pi / 2} \right) \\
&= \log y - i \, \arctan\left( \sqrt{y^2-1} \right) \, .
\end{align} $$
I'm not sure whether the imaginary parts of these functions are done correctly, especially the $\log z$ part (not sure if $\log z$ should pick up a difference in phase between $C_1$ and $C_2$).

Please correct me if I made any mistakes. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should use two cuts: $[i;i\infty)$ and $(-i\infty;-i]$, because $1+z^2$ has two zeros: $\pm i$. You don't need to use the cut $(-\infty;0]$ or any other linking zero and $\infty$, because $\ln(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})$ does not have zero at $z=0$; instead, it has zero at $z\to\infty:\,\,\ln(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})\to\ln z=-\ln\frac{1}{z}$. Two cuts suggested above solve the problem of making $\ln(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})$ a single-valued function.

Comment: Not exactly, but the similar topic https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.37#iv

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much for the reply! I did consider the cut $(-i \infty, -i]$ as well, but just didn't bother showing it since the evaluation of the integral on the contours above does not seem to depend on the lower half plane. I included the cut on the negative real axis since the integrand involves $\log z$. My question is whether $log z$ would pick up a phase difference going from $C_1$ to $C_2$?

Comment: Yes, if your integrand includes $\ln z$ - you have to include the cut, linking zero and $\infty$ - for example, $(-\infty; 0]$ - as you used. $\ln z$ does not pick up the phase difference going $C_1$ to $C_2$, because you are not going around $\ln z$ branch point in this case

Comment: @Svyatoslav Ahh...I see what you mean! Basically I should keep track of which branch cut corresponds to which function and not mix them. So for $\log z$, $\theta \in (-\pi, \pi]$; whereas for $\log(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})$, $\theta$ goes from $-3 \pi / 2$ to $\pi / 2$ around the branch at $i$ and $-\pi / 2$ to $3\pi / 2$ around the branch at $-i$?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The only point is to choose the phases on the both sides of the cut. Usually they are symmetric (of course, it depends on the symmetry of the task): for $\sqrt{1+z^2}\,$ - from $\pi$ for $C_1$ and to $-\pi$ for $C_2$  - we are turning around $z=i$ clockwise, in the negative direction

Comment: @Svyatoslav Oh, thanks for the extra insight. In the case of $f(z) = \sqrt{1+z^2}$, do you mean we normally choose $\arg f(z) = \pi / 2$ on $C_1$, and $\arg f(z) = -\pi / 2$ on $C_2$, since $\arg f(z) = \arg (1+z^2) / 2$ ?

Comment: It depends. The function $\ln(1+\sqrt{1+z^2})$ is symmetric over axis $Y$, so I may suppose this would be the right choice in your case. In other cases it can be $-2\pi; 0$ - for example, for the function $\sqrt{z}$ - if we want to have a real value of the function on the upper bank of the cut $[0;\infty)$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Could you explain in more detail the $\sqrt{2}$ case? For the branch cut chosen at $[0, \infty]$, I thought it would be $0$ to $2 \pi$ going from the upper to the lower bank (counterclockwise)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. $0;2\pi$ is more convenient, but $0;-2\pi$ is also possible - the difference is just the sign of the integral :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Got it! Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.